# Send prepared in Outlook message via php

Tags: php

I wand prepare email in Outlook in msg or otf format and send this file via php. Script must set only recipient address, all other data (embed images and text) I won get from prepared file

in other words I want prepare tempalate in Outlook, copy it to server where php script will send this template, but script will set  recipients adresses

I using google, but unsuccessfully.

Thank you!

Comment: Im not 100% sure what you wanna do - but I am sure your tryin' to do it the wrong way...

Comment: How I can do it correctly?